# Show full country on google map even if there is only one pin

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wordpress

i am facing some issues while rendering the map on my wordpress site, what i want is that even if there is only one pin, the map should show full map of that country rather than zoomed in version of that, ex

suppose this is how currently my map is showing for Denmark with one pin

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4id3g/j83y

I want it to show country in full something like this

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4id3g/ay7d

But i don't know how to do that, can anyone help me please?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bounds of Denmark (they can be retrieved from the geocoder) or create your own bounds as you desire, then use map.fitBounds with that bounds.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "Denmark"}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0].geometry.viewport) 
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8AtL2/)